# Font-Awesome icons do not display correctly on Chrome for Android

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-awesome

My Font-Awesome icons do not render correctly on the following page in Chrome for Android:

http://nylen.tv/public/chrome-issue.html

Each of the `td.description` elements (the ZZZZZ lines) has one or two Font-Awesome icons at the end of it. On my Galaxy Nexus, these don't display if the page is loaded in portrait mode. If the page is loaded in landscape mode, they do display, but if the phone is then flipped to portrait mode, they disappear.  Similar issues occur on my Nexus 7.

I don't think there's a problem with my markup. It works in every other browser I've tried, and the HTML and CSS validate except for Font-Awesome's vendor-prefixed CSS properties.

Has anybody seen something like this? Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in a Chrome for Android update.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem in Chrome...on my desktop.  Instead of the icon, a vertical rectangle was rendering in its place.

Elsewhere, in your site's own stylesheet, it's suggested you could set a height and a width of 1em and set display to :block, like so...

```
i {
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  display:block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

But I found the issue was I was not setting the relative font path correctly in the font-awesome.min.css...  Directions for doing that are here:

[http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/#integration][1]

**Make sure, too, each URL is preceded with the "src" tag...**

```
@font-face{
  font-family:'FontAwesome';
  src:url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=3.0.1');
  src:url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=3.0.1') format('embedded-opentype');
  src:url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1') format('woff');
  src:url('../font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=3.0.1') format('truetype');
  font-weight:normal;
  font-style:normal }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - unfortunately neither of them helped.  This definitely looks like a rendering bug specific to Chrome for Android.